# Fundamental Solution of the Wave Equation in One Dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am trying to prove that $$E(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}H(t)H({t}^{2}−{x}^{2}),$$ where $H(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside function, is the fundamental solution for the operator $L={∂}_{tt}−{∂}_{xx}$. Note that the fundamental solution is a distribution which satisfies $LE=δ$, where $δ$ is the Dirac distribution.

Comment: first the support of the function $E(x,t)=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } H(t)H({ t }^{ 2 }-{ x }^{ 2 })$ is the "top" of the function h(x)=|x| at the plane x,t so  the integral that I want to calculate is $\int _{ -\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \int _{ |x| }^{ \infty  }{ { ∂ }_{ tt }\varphi -{ ∂ }_{ xx }\varphi  } dtdx } $. Also 
I tried to use green's theorem to the function $F=(-{ ∂ }_{ t }\varphi ,-{ ∂ }_{ x }\varphi )$ 
but for some reason the integral over the border is zero, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make your life a ton easier if you first define the coordinate transform $u=t+x$ and $v=t-x$ and factor the wave operator as $\partial_u\partial_v$. Then, forget about the current answer and assume $E(u,v)=A(u)B(v)$. Show then that $\partial_u A(u)=\delta_{u=0}$ and similarly for $B$. This implies $A(u)=H(u)+a$ and $B(v)=H(v)+b$. Now show that $a=b=0$ because you're considering the future-time solution ($t\geq 0$).

Conclude that in the original coordinates, with proper restrictions on $t,x$:

$E(t,x):=(1/2)H(t-x)H(t+x)=(1/2)H(t)H(t^2-x^2)$